# Remove whole days from pandas hourly dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with an hourly dataframe that has rows for each hour of the day from 2016. From this hourly dataframe I want to delete some days that I have in 'df_outlayers' dataframe which is a daily dataframe. I tried the following:

```
remove = df_hourly.loc[df_outlayers.index]
df_clean = df_hourly.drop(remove.index)
df_clean['2017-04-17']
```

But it just deletes the first hour of the days, for example it deletes the row 2017-04-17 00:00:00 but not 2017-04-17 01:00:00. How can I delete every hour for those given outlayers days?

Note: My 'df_outlayers' dataframe has an index column called date, df_outlayers.index gives for example:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-06', '2016-07-08', '2016-10-10', '2017-04-09',
           '2017-04-17', '2017-04-26', '2017-07-05', '2017-07-07',
           '2017-09-01', '2017-09-22', '2017-09-29'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)
```

And my df_hourly dataframe has an index column called 'date' aswell, df_hourly.index gives for example:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-07-19 00:00:00', '2014-07-19 01:00:00', ...]
dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=13214, freq=None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted mask by `~` and [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html), because [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) return `numpy array`:

```
mask = np.in1d(df_hourly.index.date, df_outlayers.index.date)
df_clean = df_hourly[~mask]
```

Comment: I tried that, but df_outlayers.index.date has completely different length than df_hourly.index.date

Comment: Yes, my fault. Need swap values in `in1d` - `mask = np.in1d(df_hourly.index.date, df_outlayers.index.date)`